# BusyBox v1.21.1 error

Tags: boot, command-line, busybox

As I am new to the forum, I don't know where to ask this question, or even if there is a particular place to ask the question. Anyway, I have recently burned ubuntu 14.04.2 to a DVD and rebooted my computer. as nothing happened, I used power iso to run the executable file (wubi.exe) in the disk and clicked on the box that went along the lines of "get help for boot setup" I then rebooted my PC and this error popped up when I tried to install it:

```
BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

as I don't know much about Linux, I thought I might ask a question before brute-forcing my way through the built-in commands.

My history of the actions that i took plus some specs are here:

Ok, I burned the cd using Windows 7 file explorer. I have managed to change the boot priority, I am seeing different things as it is an entirely different operating system compared to windows, I am using a Toshiba Sattelite C850, with upgraded ram (8gb) it is a laptop and no, I don't have anything but windows 7 64x. although it used to be x86 but I realised I had 64-bit capabilities, so I upgraded. Also, while I had 32-bit windows, I was running OpenSUSE, but I got rid of that

Sorry in advance if this question has already been asked and answered.

also do i tell the pc when it prompts me to use it like a usb or cd/dvd player

Comment: What executable file? Do you mean you booted into your normal OS (what is it, by the way?) and tried to install from within that OS? That won't work. You need to boot from the CD.

Comment: The wubi.exe file. i ran it in windows 7 x64 since it would ignore the dvd entirely when i rebooted it. then i rebooted and it led me to the error above

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you did in more detail. The way to go is to boot from the CD though. Did you change the boot priority in the BIOS?

Comment: sorry, I don't know what the BIOS is, although i have seen it referenced on different forums

Answer (score 3):

In order to boot from a CD or USB, it is usually necessary to change the boot device priority in your BIOS. To do so, reboot the computer and, as soon as it turns on again but before the OS starts loading, hit <kbd>del</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> or whichever key your machine uses.

Unfortunately, different motherboard manufacturers have different keys to enter the BIOS setup. There is usually a message telling you something along the lines of "Press X to enter SETUP" where `X` is the key you need to hit. For example:

[image]

Once there, you need to find something that looks like this:

[image]

Then, a screen like this where you can set your CD to be the 1st boot device:

[image]

Unfortunately, the details will vary depending on your machine. You'll have to play with it a bit to figure it out. The basic idea is that you need to tell your machine to try to boot from the CD instead of the hard drive. It won't always do so by default.

Comment: ,thanks, but the error still appears, if it helps, though, another line of code sometimes appears.: (initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system

Comment: @Ben.S please edit your question and explain exactly what you've done. Tell us i) how you burnt the CD; which tool did you use? ii) clarify whether you managed to change the boot priority and if what you're seeing is different from what you get when booting normally and iii) give us more details about your machine. Is this a desktop? A laptop? Do you have any other operating systems installed? Which ones?

Comment: Ok, I burned the cd using Windows 7 file explorer. I have managed to change the boot priority, I am seeing different things as it is an entirely different operating system compared to windows, I am using a Toshiba Sattelite C850, with upgraded ram (8gb) it is a laptop and no, I don't have anything but windows 7 64x. although it used to be x86 but I realised I had 64-bit capabilities, so I upgraded. Also, while I had 32-bit windows, I was running OpenSUSE, but I got rid of that.

Comment: @Ben.S as I said, please _edit_ your question to add the extra details. It is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. Plus, the comments can be deleted with no warning.

Comment: Great answer, but at a guess I think the issue is not the computer finding the boot device but the boot device booting... if a guide for burning a disc (on Windowz) is needed you can use [this one](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows).

Comment: @Wilf yes, the latest comments suggests the OP simply copied the files onto the CD instead of burning the ISO. I'm waiting for the update to check. That link might indeed be useful, why not give it to the OP?

Comment: Whats the op? also, do i select when i put the disk i to use it as a usb or a cd/dvd player

Comment: @Ben.S the OP is "Original Poster" used for the author of the question or the post under discussion. I don't know what you mean bu use as a player, you need to burn the iso, not the files. See the link provided by Wilf in the comment above.

Comment: Thanks, but now  these errors are happening in the log: end_request: I/0 error, dev sr0, sector 1251048

Comment: terdon I did give the link to the OP as its on their question :) @BenS which log (boot, output of program)? if burning fails you can try another disc, and if possible lower the speed the disc is written too (slightly reduces chances of errors).